# Chrome lock profile on exit

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, privacy-protection

As described [here](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/05/windows/internet/browser/lock-google-chrome.html), with the new Chrome,
 you can lock your profile by simply clicking on the lock icon.

Do you think it is possible to automatically lock the profile on **exit**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That site's description of how it works is pretty bad / out of date.

If you set it up with a supervised user (which you don't even have to use) then your account will be locked every time you close chrome.

[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/lock-google-chrome-with-built-in-password-protection-1601863648) had the simplest instructions I could find, take a look for screenshots and more at the site but simply put:

- Go to chrome://flags
- Search for "Enable new profile management system"
- Click the blue "Enable" link.
- Click the "Relaunch Now" button at the bottom of your browser to apply changes.
- You will see a drop-down button with your Google account name, next to your Minimize button.
- Click the lock icon when you want to password-protect your Chrome browser. The password is the same one used for your Google account. The protection stays active even after restarting Chrome as well as after rebooting Windows.

Comment: I think the question was to have chrome locked using the normal form close action. Even better if it's locked even when the process is terminated. Ideally I would like to schedule a lock every evening in the windows task scheduler

Comment: unfortunately this feature was removed from chrome